# How to display data from collectionview inside tableviewcell to another view controller when tableview header button is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have images and labels in UICollectionView which is inside tableViewCell. I have created button on tableview header section so that when i click the button i have to go to another viewController and display data from collectionView inside tableViewCell to another viewController. I have many tableViewCells and each of it is having UIButton on tableview header and data should be displayed according to the button of tableViewCell i clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do one thing give tag value to your button in **cellForRowAt** method

```
button.tag = indexPath.row
```

Now when you click on UIButton you will get particular cell indexPath in UIButton action

```
print(sender.tag)
```

Now using this sender.tag you can get data of particular cell

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: I have created UIButton in viewForHeaderInSection function how can i assign indexpath.row to button.tag

Comment: okay so you can do one thing replace indexPath.row with section